# Regex to match beginning([) and and end(,) (only) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

This is my string:

```
[{ "name": "Neuromancer","genre": "cyberpunk" },
```

I want to remove the [ in the beginning and the come(,) in the end with the replace method.

I did this because I couldn't figure out how to write the Regex appropriately:

```
    line = line.replace(/\[/,"");
    line = line.replace(/\,$/,"");
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both regexes using `|`. And also you need tp add `^` before `\[`, since you want to match `[` char exists at the start. Inorder to make  the regex engine to find two separate matches, you need to add global `g` modifier.

```
line = line.replace(/^\[|,$/g, "");
```